# Is it possible to mark a string as non-escaped in JavaScript such as in C#?

Tags: javascript, string, escaping

I know from C#, that you can mark a string as not escaping any characters by using the @ symbol as such:

`string foo = @"\n this is actually \n";`

Is the same possible in JavaScript, or do you have to escape all characters manually?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does javascript have literal strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553738/does-javascript-have-literal-strings)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer No.
You can however post the strings in a form field in HTML and then read the string from there after the page is loaded. but that's a hackish solution and probaly not what you're looking for.