# Regex to match forward or backward slash

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this :

```
whatever/aaazzzzz
```

and sometimes a string like that :

```
whatever\bbbbzzzzz
```

I would like to split the string when I match `/` or `\`

The regex I tried seems to work

https://regex101.com/r/gP5gL0/1

When I use it in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w8hnj4ub/2/), it works with `/` but not with `\`

Any ideas?

Comment: It should be `test = "whatever\\aaaaaa"` (two slashes).

Comment: Add you actual code, so we can se why isn't working

Comment: Seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/vjxtwt2m/

Comment: What if I only have `aa\bb` and not `aa\\bb`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is not the regex itself, but the unavoidable fact that JavaScript doesn't implicitly support string literals (i.e. ones where backslashes are interpreted as printed as opposed to denoting an escape sequence. Much more can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553738/does-javascript-have-literal-strings)).

Strings derived from any source *other* than source code are interpreted as literal by default, as demonstrated in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ct4qk2ug/).

```
<script>
function splitTheString()
{
  //test = escape("whatever\aaaaaa");
  var test = document.getElementById("strToSplit").value;
  a = test.split(/(\\|\/)/)[0];
  alert(a);
}
</script>
<form>
Split this string:<br>
  <input type="text" id="strToSplit">
  <a href="javascript:splitTheString();">Split the string</a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
var arr = str.split(/[\\|\/]/);
```

```js
var str = 'whatever\\bbbbzzzzz';
alert(str.split(/[\\|\/]/))
```

Comment: As I said I don't have \\

Comment: @DeseaseSparta, (\\|\/) will not split properly, you must use /[\\|\/]/